Generate all possible pairings of letters with no repetitions in javascript
I'm playing a game where an Enigma M3 cipher is being used. It isn't meant to be played this way, but I'm finding it fun. For the current clue, the plug board for the cipher isn't known.
A plug board string looks like this: "bq cr di ej kw mt os px uz gh"
Here are the rules for this particular plug board:

Letters can only be used once: "ab cc de" is an invalid plug
It can be 0-20 characters
It must be an even number of letters: "ab" is valid, but "ab c" is not

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations in javascript but struggling. Or rather, I'm struggling to do this in the most efficient way.
Since I know the answer-plug-board is likely in English, it's probably pretty short; it's difficult to come up with long phrases under the above constraint. So it's better to try shorter answers first.
What's the most efficient algorithm to do this in javascript?

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations in javascript but struggling you haven't shown which part you are struggling with. Is it the fact that you don't have enough storage?

No no, sorry. I didn't want to clutter up the question with specifics: The part I'm struggling with is the algorithm itself. Realistically I won't be storing the output.

yeah, 150 trillion combinations is a bit big ... :p

It is and if it got there, it wouldn't be very doable. However, given the constraints, I think the space is much smaller. I think most likely the key will be something like "do ve ni gh ts" (dove nights). In which case, if you're tackling smaller keys first, it's a more manageable problem.

"given the constraints, I think the space is much smaller": you mean the constraints that the maximum size is 20, that the size must be even and no duplicates? No, that still is astronomical. The term efficient is irrelevant when you need to produce 20! permutations, even if you already selected your 20 distinct characters. 20! = 2.4e18. Multiply by the possible selection of 20 unique letters from 26 and we get 5.6e23. How much memory do you have?

Not nearly enough to contain 5.6e23 strings. Yes, I agree, if I ever start getting close to that, it's not viable. Maybe I need to revise the question, but here's the caveat: the solution to this is very likely not anywhere close to 20 characters long.
Most likely the key I'm looking for is 1) an english phrase 2) likely well under 8 characters. That's why it's important the algorithm start with the shortest keys.
I agree, 20! is ridiculously large. 8! or even 10! isn't though.

"8! or even 10! isn't though": but you need to multiply with 26-choose-8 or 26-choose-10. For 8 that means you have 6.3e10 solutions. With 8 bytes per string and some overhead you're looking at half a Terabyte. For 10, we're at 1.9e13 strings, so with 10 bytes per string, and some overhead we need 200 Terabyte.

The number of results will quickly become astronomical, but if the purpose is to just start generating them and keep going for as long as time allows, then a generator seems a useful tool here.
To keep track which letters have already been used, you could use a bit map (with 26 bits) where a 1 bit indicates the letter is still unused.
Here is a possible implementation:


// Produce pairings of an exact (even) size
function* generatePairingsOfSize(size, alphabet) {
    if (size == 0) return yield "";
    // Visit each 1-bit (which represents an available letter)
    for (let bits1 = alphabet; bits1; bits1 &= bits1 - 1) {
        const bit1 = bits1 & -bits1; // This is the bit
        for (let bits2 = alphabet ^ bit1; bits2; bits2 &= bits2 - 1) {
            const bit2 = bits2 & -bits2; // ...and a second, distinct bit
            // Get the character pair that is represented by these two bits:
            const s = String.fromCharCode(97 + 31 - Math.clz32(bit1)) + String.fromCharCode(97 + 31 - Math.clz32(bit2));
            // Use recursion to extend smaller strings with the above pair
            for (const result of generatePairingsOfSize(size-2, alphabet ^ bit1 ^ bit2)) {
                yield s + " " + result;                
            }
        } 
    }
}

// Produce pairings of all possible sizes (theoretical maximum is 26)
function* generatePairings() {
    const alphabet = (1 << 26) - 1; // A 1-bit per letter of the alphabet
    for (let size = 0; size <= 26; size += 2) {
        yield* generatePairingsOfSize(size, alphabet);
    }
}

// Get an iterator:
const iter = generatePairings();

// Demo: Using a timer to see the progress:
function loop () {
    const {done, value} = iter.next();
    if (done) return;
    console.log(value);
    setTimeout(loop);
}

loop();



If you are sure (not just "likely") that the combination should be an English word from a given dictionary, then just iterate that dictionary sorted by length, omitting words that have duplicate letters. If it can be a combination of English words, then store combinations of words (that don't exceed the maximum length) by their combined length, and iterate those.

Ah nice! Yep, this is it! Thank you! To be clear to anyone looking to do this: combinatorics is a cruel mistress. This is a massive dataset should you deign to go this route.
